# How to properly use sandbox with puppeteer on linux and stop getting insecure?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I read docs :

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_suid_sandbox_development.md

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_suid_sandbox.md

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_sandboxing.md

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_sandbox_ipc.md

But can't figure out the way to have a properly configured  sandbox, and no way to find the script `update-linux-sandbox.sh` on my system.

I've found it [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thlorenz/chromium-build/master/update-linux-sandbox.sh)

but I get :

```
$ ./update-linux-sandbox.sh
/tmp/../out/Debug does not exist. Use "BUILDTYPE=Release ./update-linux-sandbox.sh" If you are building in Release mode
$ BUILDTYPE=Release ./update-linux-sandbox.sh
/tmp/../out/Release does not exist. Use "BUILDTYPE=Release ./update-linux-sandbox.sh" If you are building in Release mode
```

The only insecure workaround I have is to use :

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch(
    {headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']}
);
```

Any idea to do the things properly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out : [enable user namespace cloning](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#setting-up-chrome-linux-sandbox) from kernel :

```
sudo sysctl -w kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're here looking for a way to run Puppeteer in Centos7 without the `--no-sandbox` arg then the @MevatlaveKraspek answer won't work

I managed to get Puppeteer taking screenshots without the `--no-sandbox` flag arg by setting a Linux kernel parameter to enable namespacing (on CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708).

As root user run: 
`echo "user.max_user_namespaces=15000" >> /etc/sysctl.conf`
Check it worked with:
`sudo sysctl -a | grep user.max_user_namespaces`

Now reboot your system and run a script without using `--no-sandbox` e.g `const browser = await puppeteer.launch();`

If it still doesn't work you might be using an older Linux Kernel and will require a couple of extra args set in the Kernel.

As root user run:
`grubby --args="user_namespace.enable=1 namespace.unpriv_enable=1" --update-kernel="$(grubby --default-kernel)"`

Now reboot your system and check the Kernel command line for the 2 params you just added
`cat /proc/cmdline`

If they are in the command line run a script without using  `--no-sandbox` again e.g `const browser = await puppeteer.launch();`

It should work now. If it doesn't you might be using an old kernel which doesn't support namespacing.

You can check your kernel version with:
`uname -a`
This is my kernel version which I've got Puppeteer running without `--no-sandbox` arg.
`Linux centos7 3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64`

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Tried this in Rocky Linux (5.14.0-362.8.1.el9_3.x86_), no success

Answer (score 6):

For Debian, in my case version 9 Stretch, the problem seems to be related to sandboxing not being turned on. Chromium will spit out the fatal-message:

- No usable sandbox!

For a solution until reboot (run from the command-line as root):

- echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/unprivileged_userns_clone

For a more permanent solution (run from the command-line as root):

- echo 'kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1' > /etc/sysctl.d/00-local-userns.conf
- service procps restart

More Debian related info can be found here:

- https://www.bountysource.com/issues/48328601-chrome-headless-doesn-t-launch-on-debian
- https://superuser.com/questions/1094597/enable-user-namespaces-in-debian-kernel

Comment: I get `/bin/sh: 1: cannot create /proc/sys/kernel/unprivileged_userns_clone: Directory nonexistent` when I try that. Not sure why...

Answer (score 1):

**You can try:**

As root user run:  `echo "user.max_user_namespaces=15000" >> /etc/sysctl.conf`

Reload sysctl: `sysctl -p`